# Activating a user account on creation in AD LDS

Tags: java, active-directory

So, I'm writing code that will create user accounts in AD LDS.  I can create the user, but the account is disabled.

I want the user to be active and to be able to change their password.  I've tried some of the things suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820883/enable-an-active-directory-user-with-ldap-java), but it hasn't helped me.

Here's my code:

```
    ctx = getConnection(adminUser, adminPassword);

    // Create attributes for the new user
    Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes(true);

    // Main attributes for user
    attributes.put("objectClass", "user");
    attributes.put("name", user.getFullName());

    attributes.put("ms-DS-User-Account-Control-Computed",
            Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED));

    try {
        ctx.createSubcontext(getDistinguishedName(user.getFullName()),
                attributes);
        System.out.println("User successfully added!");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16
>   - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D11, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v23f0remaining name 'CN=Samuel
>   King,CN=Users,CN=Agents,DC=CHESA,DC=local'    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ceiwc.ActiveDirectory.createUserAccount(ActiveDirectory.java:114)
>     at com.ceiwc.TestAD.main(TestAD.java:24)

If I change the line where I'm updating the ms-DS-User-Account-Control-Computed to:

```
attributes.put("ms-DS-User-Account-Control-Computed", UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
                + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED);
```

i get the following error:

> javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: Malformed
>   'ms-DS-User-Account-Control-Computed' attribute value; remaining name
>   'CN=Samuel King,CN=Users,CN=Agents,DC=CHESA,DC=local'     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.encodeAttribute(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.add(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.ceiwc.ActiveDirectory.createUserAccount(ActiveDirectory.java:116)
>     at com.ceiwc.TestAD.main(TestAD.java:24)

So, what am I doing wrong?  Is this the proper way to activate the account?  Does someone have any code to help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NuAlphaMan,

I think, that the exception has something to do with the fact that you use CN as the name of the attribute instead of Ldap-Display-Name which is msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed. The description could be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677840(v=vs.85).aspx.

As to the second question of how to activate an account, I've found that there is an attribute userAccountControl (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680832(v=vs.85).aspx#win_2008_r2) and the value 0x00000002 (ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) that can disable an account. The only thing that crosses my mind is to try to read the value and flip the bit.

Regards, Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchAttributeException: "Indicates that the attribute specified in the modify or compare operation does not exist in the entry."

Malformed 'ms-DS-User-Account-Control-Computed' attribute value: means wrong attribute type.

here is my working example, that i check with ActiveDirectory 2008:

```
    public void mapToContext(int userAccountControl, DirContextAdapter context) {
            context.setAttributeValue("userAccountControl", disableAccount(userAccountControl));
    }

private String disableAccount(int userAccountControl) {
    userAccountControl |= AccountControlFlags.ACCOUNTDISABLE;
    return String.valueOf(userAccountControl);
}
```